# Run WSL2 in Windows 10 guest VM running on a Linux host

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, qemu

I've got a Windows VM that I am using for testing in lieu of a real WIndows machine.  I'd like to enable WSL2 inside that VM.

So far I've:

- Upgraded Windows to v2004.
- Enabled nested virtualization in kvm-intel kernel module via `options kvm-intel nested=1`
- Made sure that `sudo cat /sys/module/kvm_intel/parameters/nested` outputs "Y".
- Set `<cpu model='host-passthrough'>` in virt-manager's xml config.

Still no dice.   As soon as I enable "Virtual Machine Platform" feature, as required for WSL2, my VM starts freezing on boot.

Has anyone managed to do this successfully?

Comment: Nested VMs are never easy. :-)

Comment: The answer here suggests disabling the hypervisor feature in the libvirt domain definition and enabling vt-d in bios. https://superuser.com/questions/1431148/kvm-nested-virtualbox-windows-guest

Comment: The same problem here with AMD Ryzen 3950X. From `dmesg`:
`Feb 21 09:37:40 charon kernel: SVM: kvm [19184]: vcpu0, guest rIP: 0xfffff81758ef848d unimplemented wrmsr: 0xc0010115 data 0x0
` The same message repeats for VCPUs 0-9 (even though the VM has 16 vCPUs in total).

Comment: This did the trick, same link as above, it worked: https://superuser.com/a/1589286/916009

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer here - to pass through specific flags that make Windows think it is on the metal, but can do nested virt, saved the day for me:

https://superuser.com/a/1589286/916009 - please note this link was posted by @JCallicoat - just saying it should be the answer

cpu definition in your virtual machine emu like so:

```
<cpu mode="custom" match="exact" check="partial">
    <model fallback="allow">Skylake-Client-noTSX-IBRS</model>
    <feature policy="disable" name="hypervisor"/>
    <feature policy="require" name="vmx"/>
</cpu>
```

Comment: Although one downside to this model is that Windows 11 is apparently not installable on it, so I do have WSL2 going but no upgrade path at the moment. If anyone knows a better model to specify please drop a note!